# Unity 3d Estimote Beacons

Tags: android-fragments, unity-game-engine, estimote, android-ibeacon

I had this error when using the android plugin with unity 3d and estimote sdk: ClassDefNotFoundError

I needed to start estimote service but it did not work inside a normal Class. So the solution
was using fragments and adding it inside the class called from unity like this

```
    fragment = new BeaconsFragment();
    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = UnityPlayer.currentActivity.getFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(fragment, "thread_beacons");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

This fragment is added without layout, then inside you can implement all the methods, like in a normal activity.

Comment: hope that can help someone

Comment: seperated out the question and the answer!